# How can I bind a ppt textbox value to an excel cell?

Tags: powerpoint, office-js, office-interop

Just like we do it in excel, reference value of another cell in current cell.

How can I do this in powerpoint shape/textbox by using `office-js` or legacy `office interop`.

I can create powerpoint slide from a template if type "=A1" in textbox and replace it by data from excel and generate a new slide, but I do not know how to link it to worksheet and update it when the origin cell changes.

Comment: OfficeJS and Office Interop are entirely different technologies with different answers.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev, I know they are different but either is OK.